# Git Rebase task for Phing?

Tags: git, phing

It seems that Phing does not have a Git task for performing a rebase.  It seems strange that it would not have a task for this, so I question if I'm overlooking it.

Can someone confirm that Phing doesn't have a Git rebase task?

Note that I'm aware a rebase can been performed when doing a pull, but this has less options than the dedicated rebase command.

Comment: You can use the `Exec` task

Comment: @hek2mgl, yeah I know.  But with that logic, Phing doesn't need any Git tasks.  And then I'll start to question why I'm using Phing when I could just use a Bash script ;)

Comment: You are free to implement such a task, it's open source! I don't expect it very complicated.

Comment: I agree that I'm sure it would be simple task to write, and I have no problems writing it.  But the question is, does the task already exists in some form?

Comment: I'm not sure but at least I couldn't find it in the manual too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no plans for a git rebase task, but pull requests are ofcourse very much appreciated ;-)

Comment: Thanks :)  I created a fork the other week, but just haven't got it yet.